# Something is limiting max output volume in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

I accidentally had the Volume Mixer opened and then I noticed the following:

[image: Not quite the same level]

The volumes aren't quite the same level. I thought about this other settings window:

[image: Configured to do nothing]

Do you know any other setting that may be affecting the maximum volume output?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify a little more where is exactly the issue (sorry for the confusing question). In the example from the screenshot, the VU meter for Spotify is clearly at nearle 100%, but the master VU meter seems to be a lot lower, like 66%. I do not know if this is by design (maybe they try to avoid hearing loss), if it is a hardware feature (not configurable) or if it is a software feature that I can configure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sound card? these often will act as an actual master volume. If not check the sound software that comes with your motherboard.

Comment: Kindly your answer should give more information in order to help user

Comment: @henry-moore, yes I have a sound card, a Sound Blaster Play! 2. It is a USB dongle. The drivers were installed from Windows Update and it does not seem to have any kind of dedicated control panel.